# Scala.js global WebSocket -> InvalidStateError

Tags: scala, asynchronous, websocket, promise, scala.js

I am trying to create a global websocket-reference that I would like to extend later down the line to automatically reconnect.

But doing baby-steps here I am not sure why this is not working as intended:

```
val uri = s"ws://localhost:1337/websocket"
var websocket: Future[WebSocket] = initWebSocket()

 def initWebSocket() : Future[WebSocket] = {
    val ws = new WebSocket(uri)

    ws.onopen =
      {
        (event: Event) => log("Websocket connection established")
      }

    ws.onmessage =
      {
        (event: MessageEvent) => log("Message received")
      }

    ws.onclose =
      {
        // TODO wait some seconds before trying to reconnect
        (event: CloseEvent) =>
          log("Close event received")
        //  this.websocket = new WebSocket(uri)
      }

    Future(ws)
}
```

I am totally aware that the (sketched) `onclose` stuff is absolute bullshit right now!

```
def main(): Unit = {
  websocket.onComplete {
    case Failure(x) => println("Epic fail!")
    case Success(x) => {
      x.send("Test")
    }
  }   
}
```

All I get is

> scala.scalajs.js.JavaScriptException: InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
>
> Websocket connection established
>
> The connection to ws://localhost:1337/websocket was interrupted while the page was loading.
>
> Close event received

**And I am *not* even wondering why!**

`onopen` is called too late... but how to elegantly solve this? I basically would need to make sure that `ws.onopen` was called before returning the websocket. I would prefer not to block but instead use some `Promise` or `Future`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. It seems like you need the Future to not resolve until after the `onopen`. So I might rewrite it something like this (mind, I haven't tried compiling this -- it might need tweaks):

```
def initWebSocket() : Future[WebSocket] = {
  val promise = Promise[WebSocket]
  val ws = new WebSocket(uri)

  ws.onopen =
  {
    (event: Event) => {
      log("Websocket connection established")
      promise.complete(Success(ws))
    }
  }

  ws.onmessage =
  {
    (event: MessageEvent) => log("Message received")
  }

  ws.onclose =
  {
    // TODO wait some seconds before trying to reconnect
    (event: CloseEvent) =>
      log("Close event received")
    //  this.websocket = new WebSocket(uri)
  }

  promise.future
}
```

This way, the Future doesn't complete immediately -- it completes when *you* want it to do so, which is after you've gotten the `onopen` confirmation. Make sense?